# how do you install and run puppeteer for firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, puppeteer, webautomation

Hi I am doing some web automation. I am trying to open a url and I am getting a data URL error in chrome console so I am moving to firefox console to get around the no data urls opening in the chrome console issue. The problem is "npm install puppeteer-firefox" is not working to install puppeteer for firefox. How can I install puppeteer for firefox and include it in the code so I can use it?

**Code not working in chrome because of data url error**

```
const url = await page.evaluate(async () => {

    
        document.querySelector('.n3VNCb').src;
        
    });
    
    url.toString();
    
    await page.goto(url);
```

**What I typed into node.js command prompt to install puppeteer firefox. This did not work**

```
npm i puppeteer-firefox
```

**Error I received from the node.js command prompt**

> npm WARN deprecated puppeteer-firefox@0.5.1: Firefox support is gradually transitioning to the
> puppeteer package. As of puppeteer v2.1.0 you can interact with Firefox Nightly. The puppeteer-firefox  > package will remain available until the transition is complete, but it is no longer actively maintained.
> For more information visit https://wiki.mozilla.org/Remote

> puppeteer-firefox@0.5.1 install C:\Users\user\Desktop\filename\filename\node_modules\puppeteer-firefox
> node install.js

> ERROR: Failed to download Firefox rv0.0.1!
> Error: Download failed: server returned code 404. URL:
> https://github.com/puppeteer/juggler/releases/download/v0.0.1/firefox-win64.zip

**I also tried these as an error said to do and they did not work**

(node:14348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find browser revision latest. Run "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install" or "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install" to download a supported Firefox browser binary.

PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install

PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install

Comment: You probably want playwright-firefox, I believe all the puppeteer projects are deprecated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a similar issue, the command you have to run is actually the following:

`PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm i puppeteer`

Source : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions

Comment: Thanks . I have been using playwright (made by the puppeteer team but they moved to Microsoft from google so I guess they had to change the name). Playwright has built in firefox support, and it work well enough. I ended up using chromium with puppeteer (not a typo). I would say to use playwright for firefox support.

Comment: Thanks, @Calahad. Didn't test because I already have what I need now with puppeteer, but I think your answer should work. Thank You

Answer (score 13):

Please don't use the `puppeteer-firefox` package anymore. It has been deprecated. Instead just install `puppeteer` with [Firefox as selected product](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#q-which-firefox-version-does-puppeteer-use). Here an [example from the puppeteer repository](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/cross-browser.js) that shows how to launch Firefox from your test script.

Answer (score 6):

type the command below to locate your browser

```
whereis firefox
OR
whereis google-chrome
```

I used chrome so, mine was. You can replace it with firefox path.

> /usr/bin/google-chrome

hence, the final step.

```
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH='/usr/bin/google-chrome'
```

that's it :)

***Note:***

You should add this variable to your shell configuration like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` otherwise after the restart, you will lose this variable value. Or more globally in `/etc/environment`

**UPDATE:**

The above answer worked for me in the past but the following is the most appropriate solution, still working for firefox.

To install firefox for the puppeteer.

```
npm i puppeteer-firefox
```

Code example tested and working for both chrome and firefox.

```
const puppeteerChrome = require('puppeteer');
const puppeteerFirefox = require('puppeteer-firefox');

(async () => {

    const test = async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1280,
            height: 800
        });
        await page.goto('https://www.bbc.com/news');   
        await page.hover('#nw-c-most-read-heading__title');
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'bcc-most-read.png' })
        
        await browser.close();
    }

    const chrome = await puppeteerChrome.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 50
    });
    await test(chrome);

    const firefox = await puppeteerFirefox.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 50
    });
    await test(firefox);

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally had a problem with Puppeteer. Can't install it on ubuntu. Just empty .local-firefox.
Playwright has webkit, chromium and firefox inside it. No problems at all. It just works

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to delete puppeteer from node_modules folder and

```
npm install
```

worked for me

Comment: This module is deprecated!